# How to fill in missing value along axis=1 with Pandas?

Tags: numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe with nan

```
a = np.asarray([[1,2,3],[2,np.nan,4],[np.nan,5,1]])
x = pd.DataFrame(a)
x.fillna(x.mean(axis=1))
```

I get

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  2  5  1
```

quite confused the last row shouldn't be 3,5,1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x.fillna()` is still column-wise operation.

```
x.mean(axis=1)

Out[73]: 
0    2
1    3
2    3
dtype: float64
```

So, first column is filled by 2, second column is filled by 3.

If I try `x.fillna(x.mean(axis=1), axis=1)`, I get

`NotImplementedError: Currently only can fill with dict/Series column by column`

Perhaps a workaround is to use transpose `x.T.fillna(x.mean(axis=1)).T`

```
Out[94]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  5  1
```

Comment: Any update on this??
The documentation says, there is an option of the axis, but having the same error,